# pymysql-ProgrammingError(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: python, pymysql

I am running this on pymysql and it appears to have a syntax problem although on workbench if i repace %s with a random value it works fine.What am I doing wrong?Also the full error row is this ProgrammingError(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3226'') \n    GROUP BY a2.actor_id=''3226'',a1.actor_id \n    HAVING count(DISTINC' at line 9")

```
sql_query='''SELECT a1.actor_id as i8opoios1 FROM actor as a1 
INNER JOIN actor as a2 on a1.actor_id != a2.actor_id 
INNER JOIN role as r1 on a1.actor_id = r1.actor_id 
INNER JOIN movie as m1 on m1.movie_id = r1.movie_id 
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg1 on mg1.movie_id = m1.movie_id 
INNER JOIN role as r2 on a2.actor_id = r2.actor_id 
INNER JOIN movie as m2 on m2.movie_id = r2.movie_id 
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg2 on mg2.movie_id = m2.movie_id 
WHERE (a2.actor_id='%s') 
GROUP BY a2.actor_id='%s',a1.actor_id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT mg1.genre_id) + count(DISTINCT mg2.genre_id)>=7 
AND SUM(mg1.genre_id = mg2.genre_id) = 0'''
cur.execute(sql_query,(actorId,actorId))
results=cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: pymysql quotes the parameters as required automatically for you, therefore you should remove the quotes `'` surrounding `%s` when using with pymysql or other connectors